# How to replace href in a bookmarklet?

Tags: html, jquery, bookmarklet

I'm trying to make a bookmarklet that changes every link on a page to "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" and I've gotten this far:

`javascript:var jq=document.createElement("script");jq.setAttribute("src","https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js");document.body.appendChild(jq);$("a").attr("href","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ%22);`

Here's it formatted if you need it

```
var jq = document.createElement("script");
jq.setAttribute("src", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js");
document.body.appendChild(jq); //install jquery because it's the only html editing language i know 

$("a").attr("href", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ%22);//replace all links
```

I do know some sites won't let you inject jQuery, but on ones that you can, the html editor shows that the href of the "a" tag has changed but won't go to the new link. This mostly happens with "/subpage" links.

EDIT:
I managed to do it without jquery:
`javascript:var a = document.querySelectorAll("a");a.forEach(function(a){a.href = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ%22;});alert(%22done.%22);`

````
a.forEach(function(a){
a.href = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ";
});
alert("done.");```

The console still shows that the link has changed, but still brings me to the link that it was previously.
````

Comment: It is really not a good idea to load 95kB of minimized code into the page in order to try to save a very small number of characters in a single statement (or even multiple statements). You're literally using more characters to load jQuery than it would have taken to do the task you're wanting in vanilla JavaScript. I understand you're using jQuery because that's what you know, but anything that can be done in jQuery can be done in vanilla JavaScript. Also, loading your own copy of jQuery can result in conflicts in the page if the page already uses jQuery or otherwise uses `$`, etc.

Comment: I haven't provided a duplicate for how to actually change the `href` attribute, as the code you've included demonstrates that you're already familiar with [`element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).